# Profiling a program with multiple modules - python

Tags: python, profiling

I am using [this framework](https://github.com/amarack/python-rl) for writing a learning algorithm.
There are multiple modules that are imported and used. 
I would like to profile this to identify bottlenecks. 
All resources I have come across provide tutorials and/or information on how to profile a single script. 
How do I go about profiling something that is run as a module like this:

`python -m pyrl.rlglue.run --load params/mountaincar/example_randtrial.json`

Here the experiment parameters are saved in the `.json` file, if that matters.

Comment: Have you tried `python -m cProfile ${PATH_TO}pyrl/rlglue/run.py --load params/mountaincar/example_randtrial.json` ? It seems like it might work.

Comment: giving the full path to `run.py` works! thanks